# Ansible: Add Cloudwatch Log event trigger to Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to add **Cloudwatch logs trigger** to Lambda function written in `python3.6` via `ansible`. I am able to deploy lambda function via ansible but facing issues when trying to deploy a trigger with a log group configured.

Below is my code for ansible trigger and lambda policy.

*Lambda trigger:*

```
- name: Cloud Watch Log event mapping
  lambda_event:
    state: present
    event_source: stream
    lambda_function_arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:<account_id>:function:CWloggerLambda
    alias: CWTEST
    region: us-east-2
    source_params:
      source_arn: arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:<account_id>:log-group:<log_group_name>
      enabled: True
```

*Lambda Policy:*

```
- name: Allowing CloudWatch Event(s) to trigger Lambda function(s)
  lambda_policy:
    lambda_function_arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:<account_id>:function:CWloggerLambda
    statement_id: "CWloggerLambda_lambda-cloudwatch-trigger"
    action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    principal: "events.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn: arn:aws:logs:us-east-2:<account_id>:log-group:<log_group_name>
    region: us-east-2
    state: present
```

The policy is added however trigger gives an error on the ARN as only `Kinesis`, `DynamoDB` and `SQS` are allowed. Any possible way to get a Cloudwatch Logs trigger via ansible?

Comment: You are using [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html) which only works with Kinesis, DynaoDB and SQS. So you can't change that. I think you want to create Cloud Watch Event rule, not Event Source Mapping? These are two different things.

Comment: I am trying to get logs from the log group using Cloudwatch Logs Trigger. Any possible way to get this trigger via ansible?

Comment: Not that familiar with ansible. Sorry.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cloudwatchevent_rule_module.html...event_source only supports Kinesis, DynaoDB and SQS. Try using cloudwatchevent_rule_module and specify the lamda arn in targets

Comment: Finally done this work using AWS CLI to first add lambda permission and then putting a subscription filter.